# How to improve the visibility of the checkbox which its in disable mode

Tags: html

Is it possible to apply css styles for a checkbox which it is in disable mode?..In diasble mode I need to keep the border as like as its in enable mode.

Comment: Refer this [link](http://www.dxdec.com/wod/formstyle/index.html#theproblem) for more options of availability. Follow this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hGptT/) to example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
input[disabled] {
...
/* CSS CODE IS HERE */
...
}
```

**//Updated CSS**

```
input[type=checkbox][disabled].asp {
/* CSS CODE IS HERE */
    ...
 }
```

Where asp i css class

Comment: aps - it's your class in css?Use it like this input[type=checkbox][disabled].asp

Comment: image border means square border.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/JfRpp/1/.....   please refer this link and see the red color line surrounding square..

Comment: You can find here custom css checboxes styles http://acidmartin.wordpress.com/2009/07/17/using-css-to-style-radiobuttons-and-checkboxes-for-safari-and-chrome/